# Trouble enlarging a lvm2 partition - "New size matches existing size"

Tags: linux, lvm, partition

I have a VM running Ubuntu. It used to have 30GB of space; I need to increase the size of the data partition, a LVM2 one, to 50GB.

I changed the size in the VM's management console and this is what `fdisk -l` tells me:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes                      <--- new size

[...]

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          32      248832   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              32        6528    52177921    5  Extended  <--- huh?!?
/dev/sda5              32        3917    31205376   8e  Linux LVM <--- old size

[...]
```

I had read up plenty of stuff about LVM first, and ended up with [this Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/424678/how-to-resize-root-lvm-partition-in-fedora-without-livecd-or-rebooting)    about resizing a LVM partition on the fly.

`sda2` seems to be the container containing `sda5`, which if I understand LVM correctly is the way things should be.

However, when I try

```
sudo lvextend /dev/DOCS/root -l+100%FREE
```

I get

```
New size (7118 extents) matches existing size (7118 extents)
```

I don't fully grasp the concept of LVM yet. Do I need to enlarge something else first, like the "outer container" of the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has come op before:

See this [How to grow LVM and underlying partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/206503/how-to-grow-lvm-and-underlying-partition?rq=1) for a way to get the desired result without having to re-create the existing partition in fdisk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the partition (/dev/sda5) first. Go into fdisk, delete /dev/sda5, create a new extended partition (/dev/sda5 - it MUST be the same number as the old one), write the changes out and reboot. Then you can lvextend.

Be careful - doing this wrong will lead to data loss.

Comment: Thanks John. I'll make a snapshot of the VM and give this a try, as I've already extended the HD this may be the easiest way

Comment: I can't get this to work without losing the entire partition complete with all data. Is there a trick to this?